# Table relationship to ensure table filters with the date slicer when the dates in table overlap

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table `Staff Booking` containing `Start date` and `End Date` for a job. I also have a calculated table filed with

```
Date Range 2 = CALENDAR(MIN('Staff Booking'[Start Date]), MAX('Staff Booking'[End Date]))
```

[image]

I want to eventually make a relationship between these two table such that:

1) When the date slicer range is defined, the jobs that overlap the slicer are filtered (using the start dat and end date columns)

2) And for the jobs that overlap, if the `start date < min(slicer date)` then `start date` change to `min(slicer date)`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a measure to the Staff Booking 2 table:

```
InRange = if(max('Date Range 2'[Date]) >= max('Staff Booking'[Start Date]) && MIN('Date Range 2'[Date]) <= min('Staff Booking'[End Date])),1,0)
```

As axample I added the InRange measure to the visual but as last step you can filter not on the InRange column by only taking the once which are 1.

[image]

Comment: Please confirm if this has helped you.