# powerbi single date filter on temporal table (effective date from and to)

Tags: date, filter, powerbi, temporal-tables

I have a table which holds a history of data changes with a date_from and date_to field.

I also have a dates table (a record for each date).

example

```
emp table
----------------------------------------
empnum    name     date_from    date_to
----------------------------------------
1         alan     20200101     20200107
2         bill     20200101     20200407
3         cory     20200101     99991231
2         bill2    20200409     99991231
```

in a power bi report i want to see the records at a point in time, so i want a single date filter and when a date is selected it does a between date_from and date_to on the emp table

There is no relationship between the two tables. I have worked out how to do it by creating a third table unpivoting the data into a 2 column table of {emp_num,date} thus connecing the two table, and this works, but the data sizes are two big when you have 100k in the emp table etc, and im sure there is a better way.

Is there a way i can filter the emp table in power bi using the date from the date slicer, when these have no relationship. I tried a visualtion filter on the table but you can only hardcode dates in these not reference a table. (that i can see anyway)

thanks

Comment: you can create a measure on your emp table, giving back true or false when you select with a filter-visual, dates from your date table. have a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60943466/table-relationship-to-ensure-table-filters-with-the-date-slicer-when-the-dates-i/60946843#60946843

Comment: ok thanks, i go this working for a table viz in power bi by adding is_in_range = if (max(fact_date_range[date_from]) <= max('Query1'[actual_date]) && max(fact_date_range[date_to]) <= max('Query1'[actual_date]),1,0). However if i were to do a pie chart now of status counts etc, it display nothing. I get confused with the context powerbi does this measure on. I essentially want this fiter done prev vis generation not post viz generation. I also can not work out how to format or do a return carriage in this reply box

Comment: I believe you know how stackoverflow works. When you appriciate an answer you vote it up..

Comment: Can you adjust your question to reflect your Pie problem, it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I’ve upvoted your answer, I’ve solved my problem, you just need to add a row level identifier as an axis column under the desired column so the max aggregation is done at row level

Comment: You did not upvote my answer, you upvoted my comment. Please on the post what has the answer, upvote it when it helped you